# Transmission continues downloading even after Paused

Tags: transmission

Using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with **Transmission version 2.51 (13280)**

I am uploading screens for better understanding.

Transmission **continues** to Download the torrent even after **Pausing** .

Not just with particular torrent but all seems to do it.  Seems to be occurring in file greater than 500 - 600 MBs .

This behaviour was present earlier version of Ubuntu too if my memory serves me right , but then ,due to Dual-boot nature i considered downloading large files in other Os.

At pausing ,

[image]

Downloading data,  even after Paused.

[image]

Comment: Does the torrent have web seeds? I have the same issue with the 31c3 talk videos, which do have web seeds...

Comment: If web seeds are involved, it is likely this bug: https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/5837

Answer (score 4):

- The BitTorrent protocol splits each file into lots of tiny pieces, each of which may be downloaded (or uploaded) from (or to) a different peer.
- Each BT client maintains a queue of the pieces which are in download (or upload) progress at any given time.
- When you "pause" a file, Transmission will still complete downloading (or uploading) the pieces which are in progress at that time.
- This behavior is easily noticeable for large files because their pieces are larger and may take a few seconds (or more) to complete.
- If you prevent this -- most commonly by force-quitting/killing the client -- the file you are downloading is left in an inconsistent state, resulting in an expensive (in terms of disk activity + time) hash recheck when you next resume the file.